I can't get text from QTextEdit (qt6, c++) and can do it with QLineEdit, i have error: The exclusion of 0x00007FF8B1552476 (Qt6widgets.dll)
I doing my project about cryptography in c++ , visual studio, using qt6 library with crypto++. I try get text from QTextEdit during the execution of the program and I have error: The exclusion of 0x00007FF8B1552476 (Qt6widgets.dll) in Crypto.exe: 0xc0000005: Violation of access rights when reading 0x0000000000000008 is caused
void MainWindow:: on_rsaPlainTextInputTextChanged()  //also not working with name on_rsaPlainTextInput_textChanged(), i dont know why
{
    //ui->rsaPlainTextInput is QTextEdit
    QString plainText = ui->rsaPlainTextInput->toPlainText();
    qDebug() << plainText;

};
void MainWindow::on_encrypt_rsa_button_clicked()
{
    try {
        CryptoPP::AutoSeededRandomPool rng;

        QString hexPublic = ui->rsa_public_key_input->text();
        qDebug() << hexPublic;
        RSA::PublicKey publicKey = rsaKeyFromHex<RSA::PublicKey>(hexPublic);

        std::string cipher; //plain
        QString plainText = ui->rsaPlainTextInput->toPlainText();
        qDebug() << plainText;

        //qDebug() << "plain size" << plain.size();  i trying without with to get text with button also

        RSAES_OAEP_SHA_Encryptor e(publicKey);
        //StringSource(plain, true,
           // new PK_EncryptorFilter(rng, e,
               // new HexEncoder(
                  //  new StringSink(cipher)
               // )
            //)
        //);

        //qDebug() << "cipher" << cipher.size();
        //qDebug() << "cipher" << cipher;

        //QString hexencrypted = QString::fromStdString(cipher);
        //ui->rsa_encrypted_text_input->setPlainText(hexencrypted);

    }
    catch (const Exception& ex) {
        qDebug() << ex.what();
        QMessageBox box;
        box.setText(ex.what());
        box.exec();
    }

}

Is will usefull to change type QTextEdit to QPlainTextEdit? Or what I need to do? With QLineEdit all works great
QString hexPublic = ui->rsa_public_key_input->text();
qDebug() << hexPublic;

screenshot of debugging

The first thing you should do is use your debugger to find out on which line of your code the error happens. Once you know that you can start thinking about the why.

I already look in debugging mode

OK, that's great, so which line of your code has the problem?

IDE does not show, but the error occurs when trying to print the text: QString plainText = ui->rsaPlainTextInput->toPlainText();
qDebug() << plainText

To me your error looks like a null pointer error. So if I knew which line of your code had the problem then that would probably be a big clue as to where the null pointer is. Of course I could be wrong, but the whatever the problem is you should be using your debugger to solve it. If you don't know how to effectively use a debugger then now is the time to learn.

If your IDE does not show where the error is, then that is only because you do not know how to use your debugger. Have you looked at the call stack? You should look at the call stack and find the most recent reference to your code.

Of you could use your debugger to set a break point, and then single step through the code until you find where it crashes.

QString plainText = ui->rsaPlainTextInput->toPlainText();      error in this line, i used debug mode

So it seems the null pointer might be rsaPlainTextInput. Again use your debugger to find out if that theory is true or not.

maybe : +  ui->rsaPlainTextInput 0x0000000000000000  QTextEdit *
i have this string . and how to solve it?

i pasted screenshot , i think you right . How to fix it? I have an object with that name.

Yes, u was right, i just changed old name to rsaPlainTextInput in ui_mainwindow.h. now all works good
